# Different conjunctions in a series (blank, blank, and blank, but blank)

Tags: conjunctions, semicolons, oxford-comma

The example sentence is just an example meant to highlight my question, not something I've come across in writing. It's a bit rough, and I honestly don't know much about policy/bills/what have you, but it's the only way I could figure out how to convey my question.

> The Senate passed something as a step toward approving The Plan, another plan, and providing money for local communities, small businesses, and families, but rejected sending COVID relief outside the country.

Because "but rejected..." can't stand on it's own, should it have a comma before it or not and why should/shouldn't it?

(Side question: should the series have semicolons as well? "The Senate passed something as a step toward approving The Plan; the president's other plan; and providing money for local communities, small businesses, and families, but rejected sending COVID relief outside the country.)